# Limit only 1 Mac device to a certain wifi

Tags: wifi

I have several Apple devices at home, but one of them is hosting some services and needs to be on a specific wifi, while the rest of my devices should be on a different network.

Is it possible to change the preferred wifi for a single device without logging out of iCloud?

Comment: The one doesn't have anything to do with the other.  If said device should only connect to a specific SSID, make sure it only has credentials for only that specific SSID.

Comment: It should be possible to set the preference order for which Wifi gets selected first in System Prefs. As Marc says, AppleID is not involved.

Comment: @MarcWilson If I tell my iMac (macOS 13) to forget one of my 2 home WiFi SSIDs I get the warning "Your Mac and other devices using iCloud Keychain will no longer join this Wi‑Fi network." So, I think that iCloud is  related to Wifi choices - all my devices will forget that SSID.

Comment: Can you say what version of macOS you are running.  I can do an answer, but can only illustrate for macOS 13.

Comment: @Gilby Well, if you're using iCloud Keychain for some reason, deleting the credential on one will remove it from the sync, so that would be a problem, I agree.

Comment: @benwiggy but does setting the preference order affect my order apple devices?

Comment: Does the device hosting services need to participate in Keychain?